# std::deque is move constructible, but not 'nothrow'

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

The question is quite simple, summarised in the title. Is there any particular reason why this should be the case? Given that objects can efficiently swap internal state, I'm certain there's something here I'm overlooking...

Comment: `deque` isn't required to be `nothrow_move_constructible`  but is allowed to be.  Here is a survey of popular implementations: http://howardhinnant.github.io/container_summary.html

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Not everyday you get a direct answer from a libc++ author:) looking at my current (clang-9.0.1) C++ headers, it's clear that the `noexcept` qualifier essentially depends on the underlying allocator properties. Was there a rationale for the relaxed requirements, or just inertia?

Comment: Inertia.  It was too big of an ask of the implementors in C++11.  But I'm hearing rumors that implementors are moving towards making everything `noexcept`.  Indeed, I haven't rechecked my survey lately and I probably should.  It is possible it is out of date.  Perhaps soon we'll be able to standardize existing practice in this area (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two deques are swapped, they are both in some valid constructed states. Consequently, swapping just requires to swap their internals, which are mostly pointers or integers (plus allocators).

However, when you *move-construct* a deque, you need to get the *moved-from* deque into a valid state, likely the *default-constructed* one. This may require some operations that may throw, such as dynamic memory allocations.

For instance, in **libstdc++**, deque's move constructor (as well as its default constructor) calls `_Deque_base::_M_initialize_map(0)`. This member function [allocates at least 2 "map" nodes](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L601):

```
this->_M_impl._M_map_size = std::max((size_t) _S_initial_map_size,
                              size_t(__num_nodes + 2));
this->_M_impl._M_map = _M_allocate_map(this->_M_impl._M_map_size);
```

In fact, it allocates at least 8 map nodes, since `_S_initial_map_size` [is set to 8](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L568).

Comment: My gut reaction was, "other containers can simply be *empty* until modified" - but I think you're on the right track - the `std::deque` complexity bounds for insertion / modification force the (default) constructor to set up some data structures on the heap - even with zero size.

Comment: @BrettHale I don't think there's any complexity bound for deque that would force the default ctor to allocate anything. It's just that libstdc++ does, and changing it would require an ABI break. (Personally I think that desperately trying to keep the ABI stable is a bad idea, but that's another story.)
Other libraries like libc++ have deque implementations where the default ctor doesn't allocate anything.